# How to order a IQueryable list of parent objects by a value in it's childs list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, sql-order-by, iqueryable

I'm trying to sort a parent list of complex objects by it's child list of complex objects based on the TextValue of a specific specification TypeId.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Specification> Specifications {get;set;}
}

public class Specification
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public long TypeId {get;set;}
    public string TextValue {get;set;}
}
```

I want to sort my products based on a specific specification of the product.
Example use case: Sort the products on the TextValue of the specification with TypeId = 3. (a product can only have one specification with TypeId 3)

My list of products looks like this:

```
IQueryable<Product> productQuery = _context.Products.Include("Specifications");
```

SortTypeId is the type of specification I want to order the Product list on.

**This is what I tried to do:**

```
productQuery = productQuery
.OrderBy(pq => pq.Specifications
.OrderBy(s => s.TypeID == SortTypeID ? Int32.MinValue : s.Id)
.ThenBy(v => v.TextValue));
```

This gives the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
Parameter name: key'
```

I also tried to sort the IQueryable by a list of sortedProductIds with Indexof but that also didn't work (IndexOf not supported for IQueryable with lazy loading).

Comment: i think, you could use `.where(x=>xSpecifications.Any(y=>y.TypeID == 3))` to filter specifications, so after filter you have one-to-one relation between product and specification. and select an anonymous object that contains `new {product, specification}` and use the `orderby` ``specification.TextValue``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say a product can only have one specification with the `SortTypeID` type, what if you join that single specification in the query and order by it?

Here's some example of what I'm trying to suggest using query syntax.

```
from p in _context.Products.Include("Specifications")
join orderSpec in _context.Specifications on new { ProductID = p.Id, TypeID = 3 }
                                    equals new { ProductID = orderSpec.ProductId, TypeID = orderSpec.TypeID } into os 
from orderSpec in os.DefaultIfEmpty() 
orderby orderSpec != null ? orderSpec.TextValue : p.Id
select p
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: A Product can have a list of specifications with TypeIds 1,2,3,4 for example. I want to order the list of products based on the TextValue in the product specification with TypeId 3.

Comment: I changed it a little bit to make it more clear, I think that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer devcrp the sorting works, I have one question left. How can I also get the products back from the lambda expression that don't have a specification with TypeID 3?

Comment: @PatrickMan try that one, I just edited it again. Basically you need to do a `left join`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413732/11350283

Comment: It works perfect, only thing that I needed to change in your query was the null check. I changed p.Id (long) to a string.